# What's wrong with my request.getParameter(abc)?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a form which has a doPost:

```
<form id="frmData" name="frmData" action="ProcessReg" method="post">            
  <td>Full Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="stFullName" name="stFullName" value=""></td>
```

I am getting a HTTP 500 error and Tomcat log indicate the line that hit `request.getParameter` part as the problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
ProcessReg.processRequest(ProcessReg.java:86)
ProcessReg.doPost(ProcessReg.java:32)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

And my servlet:

```
public class ProcessReg extends HttpServlet {

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   
     throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
  }

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    String strName = "";

   strName = request.getParameter("stFullName");

   try {
     DBConnect a = new DBConnect();
     stmt = (Statement) DBConnect.getConnection();                   
     rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM members");
```

I hope someone can tells me what went wrong cos before it was working perfectly and I really am lost where is the error.

Full stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ProcessReg] in context with path [/Web1] threw  exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at ProcessReg.processRequest(ProcessReg.java:86)
at ProcessReg.doPost(ProcessReg.java:32)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

And my DBConnect.java :

```
  public class DBConnect {

  private static Connection con;

  public static void createConnection(String dbUrl,String dbusername,String      dbPassword){
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:practODBC, 231, abc");     
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }    
}

    public static Connection getConnection(){
    return con;
}

   public static void closeConnection(){
    if(con!=null){
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Errors is not with the line `strName = request.getParameter("stFullName");` ,it's some where else.Post full stacktrace.

Comment: Full stacktrace posted.

Comment: Please post the implementation of `DBConnect.getConnection()`. It must be returning `null`.

Comment: I have added the DBConnect.java.  Is it still that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on line 86 of `ProcessReg` you are trying to call a method on an object, but the reference you have to that object == `null`, hence the [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Find that reference, and decide whether it being `null` at that point in the control flow is an error or not. If it's an error, fix that. If it's not an error, wait until you've set it to point to an object before using it to call methods on that object.

***UPDATE***

Now you've posted your code for DBConnection, it's clear there are many issues with your code. I'll try to point out the main ones, but as an aside I'd seriously recommend brushing up on the Java fundamentals [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) before going on to write relatively complex pieces of functionality like Servlets etc.

**Issues in `ProcessReg`**

you are calling `getConnection()` and returning `con`, but you haven't initialised `con` yet so you're just returning a `null` reference.

you are then trying to cast the `Connection` reference returned from `getConnection()` to the `Statement` type. This will throw a `ClassCastException`. Instead you'll want to call `createStatement()` on the returned `Connection` object reference.

all the methods on `DbConnect` are static (see below - you should refactor this) so you're instantiating a pointless DBConnect object `a`, then obviously never using it.

**Issues in `DBConnect`**

you have a static field `con`, and static methods to modify/access it. Don't do this. Make `con` an instance variable and tuck the initialisation inside the DBConnect constructor - something like this:

```
public class DBConnect {

    private Connection con;

    public DBConnect() {
        // setup con
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con; // con is never null because it's been initialised in constructor
    }

    ...
```

Then, in `ProcessReg`, instantiate a `DBConnect` object, and grab the `Connection` object it wraps by calling `getConnection()`, similarly to this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
Connection con = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement stmt = null;

String strName = "";

strName = request.getParameter("stFullName");

try {
     DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect();
     con = dbConnect.getConnection();
     stmt = con.createStatement();                   
     rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM members");
```

Comment: line 86 is 
 rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM members);

Comment: OK, so `stmt` == null, i.e. `DBConnect.getConnection()` returns null, so that's your problem. what is `DBConnect` - is that your own class? Looks like will probably be returning a `Connection` anyway, so your cast to `Statement` is going to be wrong once that returns a `Connection` reference which is not null. Use `Connection.createStatement()` instead.

Comment: I have added the DBConnect.java. Is it still that problem?

Comment: @KarenGoh there are several issues here, requiring more space than the comments. Please see my updated answer :)

Comment: @davnicwil Trying to cast the `Connection` reference to the `Statement` type will not compile.

Comment: @kapelchik no, that's incorrect - it will compile. (of course it does - the code ran to produce the NPE...) The only error would be a ClassCastException at runtime, if the returned Connection reference != null. Anyway my answer tells the OP not to do the cast for that very reason...

Comment: @davnicwil You can easily check this. Provide auto-generated implementation stubs for all interface methods and try to compile `Statement stmt = (Statement) new Connection() {//method stubs};`. The compiler will tell you `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.sql.Connection' to 'java.sql.Statement'`

Comment: @kapelchik if it doesn't compile, then explain how the OP's code ran to produce the NPE? It does compile.

Comment: Thank you for pointng out all my mistakes, davnicwl.  I learnt alot.  My question now is do I stll need the Config.java - code I posted in another thread?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `public static Connection getConnection()` method returns a null connection as you are never calling `createConnection()` whhich actually loads the driver and creates the connection object. You need to fix your `getConnection()` to call `createConnection()` before returning `con` object in `DBConnect` class.

Answer (score 0):

Make check for `null`:

```
if (stmt != null) {
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM members");
}
```

But your code looks very strange.

1. You call the static method of the class DBConnect:

   ```
   DBConnect.getConnection();
   ```

   Then why do you create the object of this class?

   ```
   DBConnect a = new DBConnect();
   ```
2. Why did you set return value of `getConnection()` method to variable of `Statement` type?

   ```
   stmt = (Statement) DBConnect.getConnection();
   ```
3. For what purpose do you cast it to `Statement`? It would be need only if your method returns the `Object` refernce type. Casting is not necessary if the return type is subinterface or any implementation of `Statement`. And casting of `Connection` to `Statement` cannot be executed.
4. Method `DBConnect.createConnection()` doesn't use taken parameters. They're hardcoded.
5. The static field `con` will remain `null` if the method has not been called or has happened exception.